# Weighted rod supported on one end

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, energy-conservation

Question regarding the setup of a problem from “Six Easy Pieces” - the content of the book is taken from the first 6 lectures or so of an intro physics course that Feynman taught at Caltech in the 1960s.

This particular problem is about a weighted rod, supported at one end, with weights placed along it.  The lecture is entirely to do with conservation of energy.

Here is the problem as given:

[image: Weighted rod problem part one]
[image: Weighted rod problem part two]

My question is whether or not the fact that the  “center raises 2 inches, and the point a quarter of the way from the fixed end lifts 1 inch” is deduced from other information given (mathematically or physically) or is an input given to the student for the sake of the problem?  It doesn’t seem that this would be deducible based on what’s  covered so far, but I’d like to be sure I’m not missing some easily computable thing.

(Feynman tends to “waive a hand” at many calculations jumping from conclusion to conclusion, so it’s easy to get lost.)

Answer (score 1):

The distances moved in this situation are all approximations to arc lengths.  Each arc length is a radius (measured from the axis at the right end) times the angular displacement. If the angle is small, the approximations are good.

Comment: In fact we are only interested in the vertical displacement of each weight, not the arc length. The distances are exact - there is no approximation. This can be confirmed by constructing similar triangles.

Comment: @gandalf61 could you expand on the triangle construction, perhaps in an answer time permitting?

Comment: If the distances from the point of support do not change then each weight, and the force from the rope, is indeed  moving on an arc.

Comment: Now that I think about, Gandald61 is correct.  The vertical components of the motion depend on the radius times the sine of the angle,  still proportional to r.

Answer (score 0):

Feynman is using virtual work to reach the same conclusion you would reach using simple statics. The virtual work method here involves conservation of potential energy. The loss in potential energy due to lowering the weight must equal the increase in potential energy due to the raising of the 60 and 100 lb weights.

The required weight can also (and usually is) be calculated by statics without the need for imagining movement of the weight $W$ which actually does not occur for static equilibrium. For statics, the algebraic sum of the forces = 0 and the algebraic sum of the moments about any point = 0. Using these equations you can determine the weight $W$ required for equilibrium (as well as the upward reaction force at the hinge on the right, if desired).

Hope this helps.